# Is it possible to load a pre-trained model into spacy?

Tags: import, model, nlp, spacy

I want to be able to use spacy's full functionality, but my language of choice does not currently have it's own model on spacy. By full functionality, I mean  convolutional layer that is shared between the tagger, parser and NER; and be able to update all of these different models by extending the vocabulary.

I need my model to do dependency parsing and named entity recognition to begin with, but I may try text classification and so on as well.

There are models in stanfordNLP that I can use for dependency parsing. I have discovered the spacy_stanfordnlp module. And this is good for getting tags and visualizing the dependency model. Is there a way to import this model (or any pre-trained model) to spacy's pipeline as as the parser? Or do I need to re-train entirely on the spacy side by using this parser's outcomes as spacy's tags and train with spacy? I want to move the dependency parser to spacy to train a NER model with a specific vocabulary on top of it, and do other tasks in the future.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
    snlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang="tr")
    nlp1 = StanfordNLPLanguage(snlp)
    nlp1.to_disk("./stanfordnlp-spacy-model")    
    nlp = spacy.load("./stanfordnlp-spacy-model", snlp=snlp)
    parser = nlp.create_pipe("parser")
    nlp.add_pipe(parser)
    # this doesnt work, with a pytorch model from tr_imst tree bank, which is used by stanfodnlp
    nlp.parser.from_bytes("tr_imst_parser.pt")["model"]
```